# Managing NSViewcontroller for OS X Development cocoa programming

Tags: objective-c, macos, view, xcode6.3, nsviewcontroller

I have integrated sqlite database in app, button I am not able to change my `NSViewController` with login button while view changes if segue is connected but than code inside login action is not compiled and `NSViewController` is directly changed. so please help as I am using Xcode 6.3 and code is written in objective c.

I am getting Assertion failure error

Answer (score 1):

I have solved issue by using method

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(NSStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

As this methods compiles code befor segue to next viewcontroller